# na.omit seems to be removing negative values in my data frame?

Tags: r

I am trying to figure out different temperature ranges for specific locations (CB, HK, etc.) in my data frame,
it looks like this:

'head(join)'

```
OTU_num location    date otus Depth   DO Temperature   pH Secchi.Depth
1 Otu0001       CB 03JUN09   21   0.0 7.60        21.0 3.68           NA
2 Otu0001       CB 03JUN09   21   0.5 8.27        16.4 3.68           NA
3 Otu0001       CB 03JUN09   21   1.0 7.65        14.9 3.68           NA
4 Otu0001       CB 03JUN09   21   1.5 5.26        12.2 3.25           NA
5 Otu0001       CB 03JUN09   21   2.0 4.01        10.1 3.25           NA
```

I am calculating the range using:

```
ranges <- join %>% 
  group_by(location) %>%
  na.omit %>%
  mutate(min=min(Temperature), max=max(Temperature), subtract=min-max) %>%
  arrange(subtract)
```

Some of the temperature values are "NA" so I used na.omit, however it appears to be taking out the negative values? so the ranges I get are wrong.

```
location min max subtract
   MA      0.1  27.3    -27.2
```

I double checked using the range function for one of the locations (there are a lot and I did not want to use range for each location)

```
    MA <- subset(join, location=="MA")
range(MA$Temperature, na.rm = TRUE)
[1] -2.2 27.6
```

Why are the values different? Any help is appreciated!!!

Comment: The values are different because `na.omit` remove a row having NA anywhere in the column.  I would suggest not to use `na.omit` and make use of the `na.rm` in `min` and `max`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you should use `join %>% filter(!is.na(Temperature))`, so only rows that have NA temperatures will be removed.